# Count variable outside custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Trying to set up a function that counts the number float values contain inside a txt file when exceeds a custom limit:

```
count_out = 0 
def testing(txts, limit, count_in):
   #tried global but doesn't work
   global count_out
   
   text = text.strip()
   values = float(text)
   
   if values > limit:
     count_in += 1
   return count_in
```

However currently, it doesn't count the number of values pass through the limit and remain at default value of 0 :

```
for a in open('sample.txt'):
  testing(a, 35, count_out)

print(count_out)
```

The values within the sample.txt are:

```
28.8
49.5
29.0
27.6
35.7
```

Comment: Although you declare `count_out` to be global, you don't modify it inside `testing()`

Comment: You can't pass immutable objects like integers as an argument "by reference". So passing `count_out` and changing it in the function won't change the contents of the original variable define outside the function (whether you declare it `global` or not).

Comment: Off-topic. The variable `text` is undefined in the code in your question and call the function will result in an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. This code worked fine.

```
count_out = 0 
def testing(txts, limit, count_in):
   #tried global but doesn't work
   global count_out
   text = txts.strip()
   values = float(text)

   if values > limit:
     count_out += 1 #change to global name
   return count_in # it return statement not nessesary

for a in open('sample.txt'):
   testing(a, 35, count_out)

print(count_out)
```

My variant

```
count_out = 0 
def testing(txts, limit):
   #tried global but doesn't work
   global count_out
   text = txts.strip()
   values = float(text)

   if values > limit:
     count_out += 1

for a in open('sample.txt'):
   testing(a, 35)

print(count_out)
```

Comment: Your code, as posted, can't possibly work because it has the same error my answer had before I fixed it.

Comment: The code in the OPs question and yours have an unbound local variable error — so saying it "worked fine" could not possibly be true,

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to pass `count_out` into your function and update it:

```py
count_out = 0 

def testing(text, limit, count_in):
   text = text.strip()
   values = float(text)
   
   if values > limit:
     count_in += 1
   return count_in

for a in open('sample.txt'):
    count_out = testing(a, 35, count_out)

print(count_out)
```

Output: `2`

Comment: Tried this already, the count_out doesn't count. That's why attempted to use global.

Comment: What does `doesn't count` mean? Actually I'm getting an error, so I'll fix that....

Comment: count_out stayed at "0" instead of adding count_in values

Comment: Code fixed and it outputs `2`. That sounds about right for your `sample.txt`

Comment: @quamrana I get this error? `could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿28.8` ..? Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like you have some extra data in front of your numbers. Perhaps you could write a new question on stack overflow where you paste the contents of your actual file into the question.